# GeoIp redirect specific country Traffic to country domain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, geoip, country-codes

I want to redirect US country traffic to my country domain from **mydomain.com**. My website is in Wordpress and i would prefer .htaccess. i have applied the below code but it redirecting all IP addresses to **mydomain.us**. Will any body help?

```
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^(US)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.us [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My Domains mydomains.com and mydomains.us has same structure like categories and post etc. i want to redirect mydomain.com traffic from US IPs to mydomain.us (but whole domain)

Thanks for answers by
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2862485/amith  https://stackoverflow.com/users/2184393/cafe-coder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really check out the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

In your case, try the following rewrite rule:

```
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.us/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: this code is not working. is there any way to check that GeoIP is working or not?

Comment: i ve VPS with Cpanel and i installed GeoIP module via WHM. I think GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE variable is not working.

Comment: @muhammadusman I meant that you should try using a proxy to change the IP address of the request to test whether U.S. based IPs are redirected correctly.

Comment: Thanks i have tried different proxies and relevant country codes. but i think my module is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rules direct non-US IP's to http://mydomain.us.

If you want to redirect US IP's to http://mydomain.com **try this:**

```
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com [R,L]
```

Or, if what you want is to redirect US IP users to http://mydomain.us, **try this:**

```
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.us [R,L]
```

It's always good to check the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: My Domains mydomains.com and mydomains.us has same structure like categories and post etc. i want to redirect mydomain.com traffic from US IPs to mydomain.us (but whole domain structure)