# How to redirect users from certain country?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the same problem of this thread:

[GeoIp redirect specific country Traffic to country domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648241/geoip-redirect-specific-country-traffic-to-country-domain)

I need to redirect users of certain country to another webpage using htaccess.

As said in that thread, after installing GeoIP, I used this code:

```
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [R,L]
```

This works great, but only for the homepage. 
But I need to redirect every page of my site. 
I tried adding this: http://www.example.com/$1
but doesn't work. Still redirect only the homepage.
Could somehome can help me understanding how fix this? Thank you

Comment: What about [**this resource**](https://htaccess.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/allow-block-country-htaccess/)? otherwise, you have to check if you are installed [tag:geoip] correctly or not.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work