# Auto Redirect Wordpress Website to Country Domain

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

we have two wordpress sites on same server, one with .com(for global users) & another is with .in(for Indian Users) domain extention. i want, if someone visits .com from any other country except india, it will be ok, but once somebody visits the same from india, it should automatically detect and notify them to redirect to Indian Domain. and same if somebody from anyother country visits .in domain then they will automatically redirected to .com domain.

Comment: Here are some posts for your help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648241/geoip-redirect-specific-country-traffic-to-country-domain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this plugin [Geo Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-redirect/).I have not used it but heard, it does the job.